# New table row(tr) is not incrementing / getting created, after the cols become 4?

Tags: php, html, loops, html-table

I'm retrieving images from the directory but all the images are shown in one rows only , So after every col 4 the row should increment and rest should be displayed on the next row..

```
$<?php

      $files = glob("images/hardware/*.*");
      //$files1=glob("images/software/*.*");
      ?>
      <div class="container">
            <h3>Hardware Solutions</h3>
      <table>

      <tr>
            <?php for ($j = 0; $j < count($files); $j++) {
            $image = $files[$j];

            //$imagePath=pathinfo($files[$j]);
            //$imgdetail=implode(" ",$imagePath);
            //echo ''.$imgdetail.''; 

            ?>
            <td>
            <img src="<?php echo ''.$image.'';?>" width="300px" height="300px" style="text-align:center;padding:10px;"/>
            <?php }?>
            </td>

      </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: The code you've shown us here shows no evidence of an attempt to solve the problem. Also the problem proposed is  a poor way to address layout issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), and using the `Modulo` [PHP Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) because your code indicates the keys for the array are strictly numbers.  Here is what it would look like:

```
<?php foreach($files as $key => $value) : ?>
    <td>
        <img src="<?php echo $value;?>" width="300px" height="300px" style="text-align:center;padding:10px;"/>
    </td>
    <?php if ($key % 3 == 0) : ?>
        </tr><tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```